# Stuck at Json, cant applyBindings to data using knockout-mapping control

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I'm stuck at applybinding. It seems ViewModel is not bound to data, Im using knockout mapping control. Please use simple jargon as I'm new to knockout and JQuery, JSON etc

**Model code**

```
 public class Property
 {
    [Key]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Locality { get; set; }
    public string HouseNo { get; set; }
    public string Block { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller code**

```
    public JsonResult GetAllProperties()
    {
        return Json(db.Property.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Javascript code**

```
    var PropertyViewModal = function (data) { }

    var property;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllProperties")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(result);
            property = new PropertyViewModel(result);
            ko.applyBindings(new property());
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

**HTML code**

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach:property">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: ProjectName"></span>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: Locality"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: HouseNo"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: Block"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: Address1"></span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Is `var PropertyViewModal = function (data) { }` your entire viewmodel or have you just omitted the detail (id expect some `this.ProjectName = ko.observable(data.ProjectName)` sort of stuff in there!)

Comment: I'm getting result something like this: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],

Comment: That doesnt answer my question.

Comment: Sorry Jamiec, I actually copied this code from some were and playing with to obtain the desired result. I want to use knockout mapping, my code may be wrong and make no sense somewhere. I need help to make it work once so that I can learn few things like JSON, AJAX, KNOCKOUT MAPPING. So if you can modify and include comments so that it help me to gain knowledge, I will appreciate it.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. giving up.

Answer (score 0):

```
        property = new PropertyViewModel(result);
```

Here you're calling a constructor to create an instance object

```
        ko.applyBindings(new property());
```

Here you're treating the instance object as if it were itself a constructor and trying to create another instance object from it. Change the line to

```
        ko.applyBindings(property);
```

All this assumes that `PropertyViewModel()` actually does something, and that `PropertyViewModal()` is simply a typo not present in your actual code.

Comment: we're also missing the fact that you can't call applyBindings() multiple times, right?